# What is correct pixel format in ImageWatch for YV12 and NV12?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, image-processing, debuggervisualizer, bgr

There is a nice Visual Studio extension [Image Watch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.ImageWatch).

It can take an arbitrary address in RAM and show its contents as an image with `@mem` operator.

> `@mem(address, type, channels, width, height, stride)`: interpret raw memory as pixels, starting at `address` (`UINT64`), with channel `type` (see [Pixel Formats](https://imagewatch.azurewebsites.net/ImageWatchHelp/ImageWatchHelp.htm#_Toc345074361)), number of `channels` (`UINT32`), `width` (`UINT32`), `height` (`UINT32`), and `stride` (`UINT32`). Example: `@mem(myimg.data, UINT8, 1, 320, 240, 320)`

According to the [help page](https://imagewatch.azurewebsites.net/ImageWatchHelp/ImageWatchHelp.htm#_Toc351981449), it can display several complex pixel formats, BGR, NV12 and YV12 are among them.

> Optionally, a format string may be associated with the pixel format. It specifies the semantics of each channel for rendering:
>
> - RG, UV
> - RGB, BGR, YUV
> - RGBA, BGRA

...

> A number of special YUV formats are supported as well. In this case, the format string also defines the data layout.
>
> - NV12 (two planes: one Y plane, one packed UV plane, subsampled by 2 in both dimensions)
> - YV12 (three planes: one Y plane, one packed U and V plane each, both subsampled by 2 in both dimensions)

However, it is not clear for me, how to make Image Watch to display images in `NV12` and `YV12` formats with `@mem` operator.

Help page does not contain too much information.

I've managed to display gray single channel images, specifying `UINT8` as a channel type. I can also correctly display BGR image with channel type = `UINT8` and 3 channels: `@mem(pBGR, UINT8, 3, 640, 480, 640*3)`. This was described in documentation, but was not obvious.

I've tried various combinations of numbers of channels and format strings with or without quotes: `@mem(ptr, NV12, 3, 640, 480, 640*3)`, `@mem(ptr, "NV12", 1, 640, 480, 640*3)`, `@mem(ptr, UINT8NV12, 3, 640, 480, 640*3)` `@mem(ptr, NV12UINT8, 1, 640, 480, 640*3)`, etc - no luck. I see only gray rectangle with the word `[invalid]`.

Same thing with `YV12`.

Comment: Aren't UV interleaved in these formats?

Comment: Yes, they are, at least in NV12. I've concluded from ImageWatch docs that it is clever enough to correctly handle it. I'm not sure, since its sources are closed.

Comment: i guess a normal solution will be to write simple wrapper structure with required fields named open-cv like style. Than place natvis file in image watch folder (tutorial describes it) make sure .planes .format and others set correct and it should work fine